# How to say "self-identify"?

Tags: translation

I've been looking online but having really found what seems like a suitable translation.

I'm try to say something like

> people who self-identify as LGBT

The best I can think of is:

> LGBTとして自己意識する方々

Any alternative/better ways to write this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen much 自己意識する outside philosophical books, and moreover it'd mean "be self-conscious" or "be self-aware".

Better literal word for "self-identify" would be 自己認識:

> LGBTと自己認識している人々

But I don't think it is a sophisticated enough word for other than academic papers (i.e. for those already know what "self-identify" means). You could also use many explanatory wording to describe what you want to say by "self-identify".

> 自分のことをLGBTと意識している人々
>   自分がLGBT（である／だ）とみなしている人々
>   自分がLGBTにあたると考えている人々
>   （自分が）LGBT（である／だ）と答えた人々
>   LGBT（である／だ）という自覚を持っている人々
>   LGBTとしてのアイデンティティを持つ人々

By the way, this is very much closer to nitpicking, but, 方々 may sound you are distant from mentioned people, so it's recommended to use this word only in a certain high honorific style that everyone is addressed by 方, or change to 人々.

Comment: Thanks, I will be addressing a room of people I don't know which is why I used 方々, is 人々 still better do you think?

Comment: Oh, if you orally speak to audience, then 方々 isn't a bad choice. I assumed you're probably going to write.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest LGBTとして生きている方々. I feel 自己意識 is a bit hard.

Comment: LGBTとして生きている sounds very much like it is a personal choice which is certainly not a nuance I want pass across.

Answer (score 0):

Self-identity is often translated as 自己同一性, but I would translate the quoted phrase, "people self-identifies as LGBT" as "LGBTとして自己認識するする人(人々), or LGBTとして自主張識する人（人々）.

Comment: Could you have meant "自己主張" instead of "自主張識"?

Comment: @goldhick. 自主 is a noun meaning self-initatedness or vountariness. There's no Japanese word, 張識, nor 自主張識.